# Converting SQL to Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

i am fooling around with the new entity framework, and just for fun io wanted to convert all exsiting querys om a old site to new and shinny linq. But i cant really figure this query out. The smallest help would be awsome.

the query i try to convert.. could handle the foreach in my c# code now so if it is leave that out, it is more the nested selects and IN that is bugging me

```
DECLARE @Begin DateTime, @End DateTime, @date DateTime, @partnerId int

Set @partnerId = 1
Set @Begin = Cast('2010-01-01' as DateTime)
Set @End = Cast(Dateadd(month, 17, @Begin) as DateTime)
Set @date = @Begin

SET NOCOUNT ON
WHILE (@date <= @End)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        [PackageId],
        @date AS [Date],
        [Name],
        (ISNULL((SELECT [ReportId] FROM [Uniferon_Reports] WHERE [FK_PartnerId] = @partnerId AND [FK_PackageId] = [Uniferon_Packages].[PackageId] AND [Date] = @date), 0)) AS [ReportId],
        (ISNULL((SELECT [UnitsForecast] FROM [Uniferon_Reports] WHERE [FK_PartnerId] = @partnerId AND [FK_PackageId] = [Uniferon_Packages].[PackageId] AND [Date] = @date), 0)) AS [UnitsForecast],
        (ISNULL((SELECT [UnitsActual] FROM [Uniferon_Reports] WHERE [FK_PartnerId] = @partnerId AND [FK_PackageId] = [Uniferon_Packages].[PackageId] AND [Date] = @date), 0)) AS [UnitsActual],
        (ISNULL((SELECT [RevenueForecast] FROM [Uniferon_Reports] WHERE [FK_PartnerId] = @partnerId AND [FK_PackageId] = [Uniferon_Packages].[PackageId] AND [Date] = @date), 0)) AS [RevenueForecast],
        (ISNULL((SELECT [RevenueActual] FROM [Uniferon_Reports] WHERE [FK_PartnerId] = @partnerId AND [FK_PackageId] = [Uniferon_Packages].[PackageId] AND [Date] = @date), 0)) AS [RevenueActual],
        (ISNULL((SELECT [UnitsInStock] FROM [Uniferon_Reports] WHERE [FK_PartnerId] = @partnerId AND [FK_PackageId] = [Uniferon_Packages].[PackageId] AND [Date] = @date), 0)) AS [UnitsInStock]
        FROM
            [Uniferon_Packages][Uniferon_Packages]
        WHERE
        [PackageId] IN 
        (SELECT [FK_PackageId] FROM [Uniferon_Partners_Packages_Relation] WHERE [FK_PartnerId] = @partnerId AND [StartDate] <= @date    AND ([EndDate] >= @date OR [EndDate] IS NULL))


Set @date = DateAdd(month, 1, @date)
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

any thoughts ?

Comment: Why do you need to change it? It is OK to use more than one tool... if LINQ/EF makes that hard... don't use them for that, IMO. Especially in the case of what looks like a report query, you probably don't need a full ORM for that. Have you considered using something simpler? Raw ADO.NET? A Micro-ORM such as "dapper"? I don't mean for everything - I just mean to run this existing and working TSQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Hope this will help you to understand LINQ more effective ;) :

```
while (date <= endDate)
{
    var result = Uniferon_Packages
        .Where(i => 
            Uniferon_Partners_Packages_Relation.Any(rel => rel.FK_PartnerId == i.PackageId) &&
            rel.StartDate <= date && (!rel.EndDate.HasValue || rel.EndDate >= date))
        .Select(i => new
                         {
                             i.PackageId,
                             i.Name,
                             Date = date,
                             ReportId = GetReportId(i, partnerId, date)
                             // etc...
                         });

    date = date.AddMonths(1);
}


private int GetReportId(Uniferon_Package pack, int partnerId, DateTime date)
{
    var report = Uniferon_Reports.FirstOrDefault(x => 
        x.FK_PartnerId == partnerId && 
        x.FK_PackageId == pack.PackageId && 
        x.Date == date);

    return report != null
        ? report.ReportId
        : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool available called [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com) which can take your SQL statements and convert them into lamba functions. Give that a go and see what it can produce.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing to do is to try to understand the original SQL - then you can look at writing the query in Linq.

Looking at it briefly, it looks to me like the SELECT of the original query might itself be a poorly written outer join? It might be worth looking at that...

However, do bear in mind that if the WHILE is really needed within the SQL, then you might not be able to efficiently port this across to client side C# code - if a loop on the database is required then it might be more optimal to leave this code in server-side SQL.

Comment: you are so right about the left outer join. but i cant see how i should get the same values as now, cause i get the row out even if it has no "values" and that is what i need cause the the user needs to put values in.

Comment: sorry - but that sentence didn't make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) which could help you learn LINQ and check your LINQ Expression is right or not.